# How can I deploy a resource-adapter activation in JBoss 7?

Tags: maven, jms, jboss7.x, activemq-classic, jca

I am trying to figure out how to deploy a resource-adapter activation in JBoss 7. Basically, I want to be able to package and deploy a full application without having to modify the base server configuration, in part because I want to bootstrap testing using Arquillian but also because I want to be able to deploy my packages into an environments where I may not have the option of modifying the base server's configuration.

Here's where I am right now. I have created an EAR which contains the active-mq rar (which is also configured in the application.xml). This ear by itself builds and deploys perfectly using the maven ear plugin and the jboss-as-maven-plugin.

However, in order to activate the rar, the only way I have been able to figure out is to hack the rar file itself and add an **ironjacamar.xml** into the rar's **META-INF** directory. But in order to do this, I had to hack the rar in my maven repo which I don't really want to do.

I tried to get maven to add the **ironjacamar.xml** during the packaging phase of my maven pom, but that's a bit of hack as well and I couldn't get it work anyways.  (Note to self: check on [Deployment Overlays](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Deployment+Overlays))

I also thought about scripting the addition of a **connection-factory** using jboss-cli, but the docs clearly state that is for creating factories for the built in hornet-mq server which is not my target, and swapping the default JMS implementation in the server requires some major surgery on the server's config.

I looked though all the quickstart projects and observed all sorts of constructs being deployed though **-jms.xml** and **-ds.xml** files included in the package, but they're also specific to hornet-mq and JDBC respectively. (I was hoping the deployer might support a **-rar.xml** or the like).

The only other way I can think of, and I don't know if it is supported, is to define a ***subsystem*** deployment in my package. Is there such a thing ?

===== UPDATE =====

I tried adding a cli overlay update (as I would using the maven jboss as plugin) but it had no effect.

```
deployment-overlay add --name=rarActivation  --content=META-INF/ironjacamar.xml=\..\container\src\main\resources\ironjacamar.xml --deployments=activemq-rar.rar --redeploy-affected
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in the absence of any other answers, this is the solution I came up with. It's a bit of a hack, but it has worked flawlessly with Active MQ and WebSphere MQ. The premise is that I deploy 2 different RARs per JMS system I want to connect to. One is the untouched xxx.rar file I retrieve from the Maven repository. The second is my "configuration RAR" which contains a copy of the **ra.xml** from the original rar, and then an **ironjacamar.xml** configuration file. Both of those are placed in the config rar's **META-INF** folder.

For each given vendor RAR, the **ironjacamar.xml** file can be generated using **rar-info.sh** which is included in the Iron Jacamar 1.1 download. The procedure is described in the section titled [10.1. Resource adapter information tool](http://www.ironjacamar.org/doc/userguide/1.1/en-US/html_single/index.html#tools_rarinfo) int the [user guide](http://www.ironjacamar.org/doc/userguide/1.1/en-US/html_single/index.html).

***Using ActiveMQ 5.8.0 as an example:***

The generated **ironjacamar.xml** is extracted from the full output of the **rar-info.sh** output. Within the file, it is titled:

```
Deployment Descriptor:
----------------------
```

The extracted part of the file that will become **ironjacamar.xml** starts after that header and ends with **</resource-adapters>**.

The following edits should be applied:

1. Remove the opening `<resource-adapters>` and `<resource-adapter>` tags and replace with an `<ironjacamar.xml>` opening tag.
2. Remove the opening `<archive>` tag.
3. Remove the closing `</resource-adapter>` and `</resource-adapters>` tags and replace with an `</ironjacamar.xml>` closing tag.

There are sample definitions for connection factories for each type of connection (Connection, Queue and Topic) which include a JNDI name where JBoss will bind the factories to. Edit these as you see fit. I only needed the Connection factory so I edited the JNDI name and deleted the other two definitions.

There are sample definitions for destination references (which are almost un-necessary with ActiveMQ, but it's helpful for others). One for a queue, one for a topic. Edit these as you see fit.

The maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-rar</artifactId>
  <version>5.8.0</version>
  <type>rar</type>
</dependency>
```

The deployable EAR looks like this:

```
sample.ear
    META-INF
        application.xml
    activemq-rar.rar  (file)
    activemq-config.rar  (directory)
        ra.xml   (extracted from activemq-rar.rar or generated)
        ironjacamar.xml  (generated, then edited)
```

Actually, the ra.xml can be extracted from the "real" rar, but it is also generated in the IronJacamar **rar-info.sh** output file, so take it from either.

The **application.ear** then looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
  <display-name>JBoss7Sample Ear</display-name>
  <!--   Sample for WebSphereMQ
  <module><connector>wmq.jmsra.rar</connector></module>
  <module><connector>wmq-config.rar</connector></module>
  -->
  <module><connector>activemq-rar.rar</connector></module>
  <module><connector>amq-config.rar</connector></module>  
</application>
```

To re-emphasize, this (actually quite simple) work around is important to me because any deployment procedure that starts with *"Edit the server file called.....*  or "*In the management console.....*" is a non-starter in the environment I am targeting. I need to assume no access to a vanilla JBoss 7 (EAP 6.1) internal directories, nor access to the console, as one might deploy at the end of a Jenkins build or the like.. (Not to mention which, editing files to add a deployment is a non-starter all by itself).

This workaround and others can be viewed in more detail in this [github project](https://github.com/nickman/jboss7Sample) which was setup specifically to share some working configurations which I have found are otherwise fairly difficult to come by.

**P.S.**  Since this is the only offered answer, I am awarding the correct answer to myself, but I'll give it up for a better answer.