# set hostname etc. from Websphere MQ Resource Adapter dynamically

Tags: java, ibm-mq, jca

I'm currently struggling with the Websphere Resource Adapter for MQ JMS on the JBoss AS 7.1. The adapter itself works great, but I should be able to set some properties dynamically. For example hostName etc.

Currently I have to set the hostName, port etc. for the mq-connection "hard-coded" with a property-file.

For example: `mq.hostname = localhost:1421.`

Now my question. Is it possible to set this via coding? The problem is that I can't edit the MQ Adapter from IBM because of the copyright and the non-available source-files.

My first idea was, to add a second resource adapter which gets called first and which sets the property of the IBM MQ adapter. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your first idea will work. It took me a while to figure it out, but the procedure is outlined in my answer to my question [How can I hot deploy a resource-adapter activation in JBoss 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033892/how-can-i-hot-deploy-a-resource-adapter-activation-in-jboss-7)

Basically, you will [deploy the WMQ RAR](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Deploy_the_WebSphere_MQ_Resource_Adapter.html) (wmq.jmsra.rar) as is. Then you deploy a configuration only RAR which contains the **ra.xml** from the wmq.jmsra.rar archive and an ironjacamar.xml (both in the META-INF sub-folder).

You can find the details in the link. The *official* way to do this, though, is to follow the procedure outlines in the 2nd link above. I avoided this because I wanted a full WMQ RAR deployment and configuration to be deployed into a vanilla AS7 server, and the official procedure requires editing a few internal configuration files in the AS7 install.

Here's an example [WMQ ironjacamar.xml deployment descriptor](https://gist.github.com/nickman/37c5d7c66d11498908e4#file-ironjacamar-xml).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. But I have one more question. As I said I have to edit the property via code. How can I change the properties when the wmq already has been deployed.

Comment: So when a message was sent, I'd like to take that message and set the properties of the wmq rar for example with setProperties("key", "value") or something like that.