# how to deploy resource adapter in jboss

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I am trying to deploy a rar which is packed inside an ear. I have the ra.xml packed inside the rar. I am trying to deploy it in jboss eap 6.x and I get the below error

> {
>       "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"jca-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"shm-jca-file-adapter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.rar\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.ser
>   vice.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"jca-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"shm-jca-file-adapter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.rar\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process
>    phase INSTALL of subdeployment \"shm-jca-file-adapter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.rar\" of deployment \"jca-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\"
>       Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"},
>       "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"jca-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".deploymentCompleteService is missing [jboss.de
>   ployment.subunit.\"jca-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"shm-jca-file-adapter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.rar\".deploymentCompleteService]"]
>   }

Actually I tried searching many sites online. Every tutorial explain only the main parts and provides links to a sample resourceadapter application. All links are expired.

Can anyone please help me?

Previously I used to use glassfish app server and there used to be another file glassfish-resources.xml. I did not find jboss equivalent for the same file.

My ra.xml like something like below

```
<resourceadapter>
    <outbound-resourceadapter>
        <connection-definition>
            <managedconnectionfactory-class>com.resourceadapter.impl.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl</managedconnectionfactory-class>
            <connectionfactory-interface>com.resourceadapter.FileConnectionFactory</connectionfactory-interface>
            <connectionfactory-impl-class>com.resourceadapter.impl.FileConnectionFactoryImpl</connectionfactory-impl-class>
            <connection-interface>com.resourceadapter.FileConnection</connection-interface>
            <connection-impl-class>com.resourceadapter.impl.FileConnectionImpl</connection-impl-class>
        </connection-definition>
        <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
    </outbound-resourceadapter>
</resourceadapter>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your looking [How can I hot deploy a resource-adapter activation in JBoss 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033892/how-can-i-hot-deploy-a-resource-adapter-activation-in-jboss-7)

You need add the specific configuration `META-INF/ironjacamar.xml`, for the activation of resource adapters

[[JBoss7] Resource Adapter in EAR](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/213987)

[Resource adapters JBoss 7 Docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Resource+adapters)